# How to add the X axis into an already created line chart using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I got this problem:

I am using VBA, to make some charts.

I made some input fields...those input fields are transferred via button to a table, and from that table, I draw the line chart.

Looks like this:

Answers in column D, they are all changeable, but the number is constant, always 12...

[image]

Then I got the table, where on button press, the answers are transferred:

[image]

Point is, on button click, I add a new row to the table, the last rows (from S to AB) are generic data, which I make with formulas out of the answers.

Once I add the new row, I also add the time stamp to the left side...

Now, I am ready to make a line chart...with the last 4 columns Y, Z, AA and AB
I made it, but I don't know how to add the timestamp to be on the x axis.

Timestamp looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code of my button:

```
Sub AddData()
'
' AddData Macro
' Adds data to the table
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim rowSize As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim myRange As Variant
Dim cell As Variant
Dim column_Position As Integer
Dim row_Position As Integer
Dim rangeFormula As Variant

rowSize = 12
row_Position = -1
Set myRange = range("G1:G1000")

'Find first empty row
For Each cell In myRange
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        column_Position = cell.Column
        row_Position = cell.row
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell

'Do for loop and fill the cells from G(7) to R(18) with data
For i = 1 To rowSize
    cellValue = range("D2:D13").Cells(i).Value
    range(Cells(row_Position, "G"), Cells(row_Position, "R")).Cells(i).Value = cellValue
Next i

'Copy formulas one row bellow, from S(19) to AB(28)
If row_Position > 4 Then
    range(Cells(row_Position - 1, "S"), Cells(row_Position - 1, "AB")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    range(Cells(row_Position, "S"), Cells(row_Position, "AB")).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False
End If

'Add timestamp to F cells
Cells(row_Position, "F") = Now()
Cells(row_Position, "F") = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

'Remove Selections
Cells(1, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Delete all old charts
If Not Worksheets("Data").ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Data").ChartObjects.Delete
End If

'Draw a chart
Dim rng As range
Dim cht As ChartObject

'Your data range for the chart
Set rng = ActiveSheet.range(Cells(2, "Y"), Cells(row_Position, "AB"))

'Create a chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
    Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
    Width:=775, _
    Top:=275, _
    Height:=250)

'Populate chart with data
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

'Add gridlines
cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

'Determine the chart type
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines


cht.Activate
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=$F$4:$F$28"
```

End Sub

Now, I have something like this:

[image]

A line chart with the 4 rows I used to make the chart.

But I have no idea how to add the F(F4 to last filled row) column as the x axis.

Edit1: Forgot to mention, once I add the row to the table, the current chart is deleted, and I make a new one, with the all data as before, plus the new row...

Edit2: Thanks to Pierre44, I moved the timestamp column a row higher, and added one extra row, so that the arrays all have the same length...and it looks like this:

[image]
Please help.

And it is almost done, but can you show me how to move the x axis, bellow the graph?

Like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: It s quite hard to follow your question as it is so long. What do you exactly need? Only the timestamp (an additionnal column) inside your new chart?

Comment: yes, that is correct... the question is in the title?

Comment: I added an example for the orientation in my answer, I am not sure that this is what you need

Comment: thats cool...thx, gonna keep that....but can u show me how to move the xaxis to the bottom of the chart, like just like in the second picture in the second edit?

Comment: TickLabelPosition = xlLow (as in my edit)

Comment: Thanks man, u saved me....I sit on this problem, for like 20 hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to define the whole range of your graph from the beginning:

For this you can replace:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.range(Cells(2, "Y"), Cells(row_Position, "AB"))
```

By:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("Sheet1!$F$1:$F$" & row_Position & ",Sheet1!$Y$1:$AB$" & row_Position)
```

Note that I changed F4:F28 to "F1:F" & row_Position as you need to have as many values here as you have in the other columns

As your X values are quite long, you might want to change their orientation
Example:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlLow
```

Comment: First, let me say that i appreciate you for taking time for me, also, I tried you solution, and thx, for the missing row, Is there a way for me to ignore the 1st row in that selection, cause, they are all generated zeros....not important...and I did your code, and the cart didn't have the dates as the x axis :(

Comment: thanks for your advise, I moved the timestamp one row up, used =Now() function there and modified the number by 1, now i am almost there....I get the dates as XAxis, but it kinda looks weird...please take a look on the edited question i a minute

Comment: So your X Axis should have only the minutes / seconds? You will always have the same date I guess

Comment: dont worry, i ll need the dates as well...please take a look on the question again, on edit2 and bellow...

Comment: sorry for bothering you again....but can you show me how to make the chart look equidistant? I mean, that the chart can look ugly if the data is submitted in very different time periods....I want the markers always to have the same distance from each other....can u help me?

Comment: Sure, can you ask it inanother question? maybe other people will have the same one